# Why stop or rm with profiles stop all service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to `stop` or `rm` services by passing a profile, but this stops all services instead of just the one with this profile.
The `up` command seems to work fine
This is my `docker-compose.yaml`
version: '3.9'

```yaml
services:
  registry:
    container_name: registry
    image: registry:latest
    pull_policy: missing
    profiles:
      - registry_service_profile
    ...

  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: localhost:5000/my-portainer
    pull_policy: missing
    profiles:
      - other_services_profile
    ...

  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: localhost:5000/my-pihole
    pull_policy: missing
    profiles:
      - other_services_profile
    ...

  bitwarden:
    container_name: bitwarden
    image: localhost:5000/my-bitwarden
    profiles:
      - other_services_profile
    pull_policy: missing
    ...

  homeassistant:
    container_name: homeassistant
    image: localhost:5000/my-homeassistant
    pull_policy: missing
    profiles:
      - other_services_profile
    ...

  duplicati:
    container_name: duplicati
    image: localhost:5000/my-duplicati
    pull_policy: missing
    profiles:
      - other_services_profile
    ...
```

Running the stop command with both profiles stops all services, not just the ones with the provided profile

```sh
user@pc:/opt/docker$ sudo docker compose --profile registry_service_profile stop
[+] Running 6/6
 ⠿ Container pihole         Stopped                                                                                                              4.6s
 ⠿ Container portainer      Stopped                                                                                                              0.7s
 ⠿ Container registry       Stopped                                                                                                              0.4s
 ⠿ Container homeassistant  Stopped                                                                                                              5.0s
 ⠿ Container bitwarden      Stopped                                                                                                              0.5s
 ⠿ Container duplicati      Stopped                                                                                                              4.5s
user@pc:/opt/docker$ sudo docker compose --profile registry_service_profile up --detach
[+] Running 1/1
 ⠿ Container registry  Started                                                                                                                   0.4s
user@pc:/opt/docker$ sudo docker compose --profile other_services_profile up --detach
[+] Running 5/5
 ⠿ Container portainer      Started                                                                                                              0.7s
 ⠿ Container homeassistant  Started                                                                                                              0.2s
 ⠿ Container bitwarden      Started                                                                                                              0.6s
 ⠿ Container pihole         Started                                                                                                              0.9s
 ⠿ Container duplicati      Started                                                                                                              0.9s
user@pc:/opt/docker$ sudo docker compose --profile other_services_profile stop
[+] Running 6/6
 ⠿ Container portainer      Stopped                                                                                                              0.4s
 ⠿ Container pihole         Stopped                                                                                                              4.5s
 ⠿ Container registry       Stopped                                                                                                              0.6s
 ⠿ Container duplicati      Stopped                                                                                                              4.4s
 ⠿ Container homeassistant  Stopped                                                                                                              5.0s
 ⠿ Container bitwarden      Stopped                                                                                                              0.5s
user@pc:/opt/docker$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Or I should just run `docker compose up` command and this should update the services to the latest pulled version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to stop only the services that contains the profile `other_services_profile` and not all the containers

I think you can't and this is still an issue of docker compose
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8139

NB: I tried to reproduce it, for me this behavior happens when using
`docker compose --profile other_services_profile stop`
but not when using
`docker compose --profile other_services_profile down`, in this case it remove all containers with only that profile (you will also get a message of it trying to delete the default network aswell but cannot as long as there is one container running still using it)

(I use docker 20.10.17 on windows)

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation choice. The profiles only work when creating or starting services. Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8139#issuecomment-1113185262)

Comment: yes, this seems to be the behaviour of `docker-compose`, but according to the comment below, `docker compose` is supposed to work with profiles even with down stop and rm https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/8139#issuecomment-1113194178